# Flutter Firestore Array add Items in List

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i wanna add a data.value() from Firebase Firestore items in a List,

i got 10 Item in Firestore Array, and all items will be showed in List ,

here im getting the Doc as ,

```
docCek() {
    firestoreInstance.collection("icerik").doc("TYT").get().then((value) {
      //print(value.data());
      int itemCount = value.data()!["dersler"].length;
    });

    update();
  }
```

result is :

```
I/flutter (11270): [Türkce, Matematik, Geometri, Fizik, Kimya, Biyoloji, Tarih, Cografya, Felsefe, Din Kültürü]
```

and i got a Local RxList , i wanna add all items in List with for , but for Loop is not going ,

```
  var dersler = [].obs;
```

and my Function with For Loop

```
   docCek() {
    firestoreInstance.collection("icerik").doc("TYT").get().then((value) {
      //print(value.data());

      print(value.data()!["dersler"]);
      print(value.data()!["dersler"].length);

      int count = value.data()!["dersler"].length;

      for (var i = 0; i >= count; i++) {
        dersler.add(value.data()!["TYT"]);
        print(dersler.toString());
      }
    });

    update();
  }
```

how can i add all items from result to dersler List ?

Thanks !

Comment: I think your for loop has inverted logic. Your condition is true for values of `i` that larger than `count`.  Try `for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {`

Comment: Waow Nice its working right now ! :D But only null,null,null !

Comment: I don't know what your data structure looks like, but I suspect you are calling the wrong key in `dersler.add(value.data()!["TYT"]);`. Is `TYT` the correct key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it right now, i add only addAll Function and here is the new Code ,

```
 docCek() {
    firestoreInstance.collection("icerik").doc("TYT").get().then((value) {
      //print(value.data());

      print(value.data()!["dersler"]);
      print(value.data()!["dersler"].length);

      int count = value.data()!["dersler"].length;

      dersler.addAll(value.data()!["dersler"].toList());

      /*  for (var i = 0; count > i; i++) {
        dersler.addAll(value.data()!["dersler"].toString());
        print(dersler.toString());
     }*/
    });

    update();
  }
```